# Calculate Var(XY)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was practicing and came across this, which I couldn't solve.

**Calculate Var(XY) where X ~ Uniform(0,1) and Y ~ Normal(0,1)**

Comment: Yes but the question says $\operatorname{Var}(XY)$ not $\operatorname{Var}(aX+bY)$.

Comment: And are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W=XY$. We want to calculate $E(W^2)-(E(W))^2$.

On the (unstated) assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are **independent**, all we need is $E(X^2)$ and $E(Y^2)$, since $E(Y)=0$.

The calculation of $E(X^2)$ is an easy integration. And since $\text{Var}(Y)=E(Y^2)-(E(Y))^2$, we have $E(Y^2)=1$.

Comment: Is it true that $E(Z^2)=E(X^2)E(Y^2)$?

Comment: On the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, yes. If $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, we need information about the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ to solve the problem.

Comment: How does the factorization of the joint distribution as $f_x(x)f_y(y)$ lead to this? *(I'm not doubting it I just can't quite see it.)*

Comment: thanks for the easy explanation.

Comment: @Dan: When we calculate $\iint x^2y^2f_X(x)f_Y(y)\,dx\,dy$, the integral becomes $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2f_X(x)\,dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2f_Y(y)\,dy$.

Comment: Clearly. But this first integral is equal to $\int z^2 f_z(z) dz$ I take it? It's that step which is not so obvious to me since each $z$ has a non unique $x,y$.

Comment: True, there is a large gap here that cannot be filled in a comment! In general, $g(X,Y)$ is a random variable $W$. In principle, the expectation of $W$ is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty wf_W(w)\,dw$. But if $g$ is a "nice" function then $E(f(X,Y))=\iint g(x,y)f_{X,Y}\,dx\,dy$. This is sometimes called the law of the unconscious statistician.

Comment: Ahh okay, I've used this many times for 1d I didn't know it generalized so simply. Thanks.